# How to set required field only for default language?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this input, where i enter for languages some text. Now i want to set required field but only if its language code [de]. When i do like this i get required field for all languages. Any suggestion how can i fix this?

```
  @foreach ($languages as $language)
        <input type="text" id="text-title" name="article_title[{{$language->code}}]" value="" class="form_input"  />
    @endforeach

  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'article_title[de]'             => 'required:articles',
            'slug'                          => 'required|unique:articles',
            'article_intro[de]'             => 'required:articles',
            'article_content[de]'           => 'required:articles',
            'article_category[de]'          => 'required|exists:categories,id',
        ];
    }
```

EDIT:

I found this solution, it works for me.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-dynamic-form-validation?page=1

Answer (score 0):

You can check langauge with reuquest if you have url like: www.xxxxx.com/de or you can pass hidden input with lang value and than:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="de">
```

Request:

```
if(request()->segment(2) == 'de') {
    return [
        'article_title[de]'             => 'required:articles',
        'slug'                          => 'required|unique:articles',
        'article_intro[de]'             => 'required:articles',
        'article_content[de]'           => 'required:articles',
        'article_category[de]'          => 'required|exists:categories,id',
    ]
} else {
    return [];
}
```

or with hidden input

```
if(request()->lang == 'de') {
    return [
        'article_title[de]'             => 'required:articles',
        'slug'                          => 'required|unique:articles',
        'article_intro[de]'             => 'required:articles',
        'article_content[de]'           => 'required:articles',
        'article_category[de]'          => 'required|exists:categories,id',
    ]
} else {
    return [];
}
```

Comment: its not working... even when i enter data in field it say its required

Comment: Maybe return is required so I added else return [], and check dd(request()->segment(2) == 'de') at a start of method to see in which statement your code goes...